# What is inside a telephone handset?

Tags: wiring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine 4p4c wiring](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/43195/determine-4p4c-wiring)

This might sound highly trivial, but search in google for it, you won't find a circuitry.

So what does a handset's circuitry look like?

And: What's the wiring for german 4P4C connectors? This is - you might not believe it - not in google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "you won't find a circuitry"

Sure you will. It took me less than a minute to find this

[image]

on Wikipedia.

Comment: I know that but the german version has brown, white, yellow and green. Also I don't understand what the 500 Ohms resistor does. Do you?

Comment: @Zurechtweiser - Ah! Aber denn muß ich dich *zurechtweisen*! :-) You didn't mention colors in your question. The resistor may be to make the speaker's load less inductive, but I would have to see what's on the other end to be sure.

Comment: I looked at my socket, assigned the numbers from your drawing to my colors et voila it worked. So your finding wasn't the answer but led me to it so I give you a thumbs up.